# Why don't Michonne's walker drones try to attack her?

Tags: the-walking-dead

**As in the title:**
Why don't Michonne's walker drones try to attack/bite her (or someone else)? Are they aware of the fact, that they don't have any arms and a jawbone anymore?

**Further:**
 
In some scenes, she also seems to control them a little (like to move or stop walking). How is that possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has been adressed here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49840/why-didnt-michonnes-tied-up-zombies-try-to-eat-her

Answer (score 3):

## Why don't Michonne's pets try to attack her?

Basically, because they can't.  They have no arms or teeth.  The fact that they stopped trying to do so implies that they somehow learned that it would never work, but how they learned this (since zombies can't learn) is never really explained.  All we know is what we're told.

### In the comics:

[image]

> These two stopped trying to attack me a long time ago.
>   -  Michonne, *Issue 19; Volume 4:  The Heart's Desire*

### On the show:

> Pretty impressive, really, major kudos for ingenuity. Take away their arms so they can't grab you, take away their jaws so they can't bite you, take away their ability to eat, they lose interest in doing so. They're no longer in attack mode, we can be in their presence without threat. They become docile, in a sense.
>   -  Milton, Season 3 Episode 3:  *Walk With Me*

## Why do the pets seem to obey Michonne sometimes?

We don't know.